# How to use xaml style in code?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

While desing my GUI, I defined a style for a shape in the xaml file like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Data" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartRectangleStyle}">        
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Data_DragThumb" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Data}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>        
</Style>

<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource Data}" ToolTip="Data" StrokeThickness="2">                
     <s:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate>
         <ControlTemplate>                        
             <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource Data_DragThumb}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
     </s:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate>
</Rectangle>
```

While saving the output, there is a content property of this shape in the output xml file. Now I want to use this same shape (more precisely, its content) to create an XElement with same content property. For that I tried this one:

```
XElement myNewItem;
... ... //assign some other property values here
Object dataShape = Application.Current.Resources["Data_DragThumb"];
myNewItem.Content = dataShape;
```

But this does not give me the exact content values of the shape as appeared in the GUI output xml file, but instead just gives a string something like "system.windows.style". Actually I was hoping to see the same shape when visualizing 'myNewItem' here after giving content values. How can I solve this? Thanks.

**Update**

The output xml file stores the shape as data like this:

```
<Content>&lt;Rectangle StrokeThickness="2" ToolTip="Data" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner;assembly=ADAX_GUI"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Fill"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBE9" Offset="0" /&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFFA500" Offset="1" /&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stroke"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#FFD69436&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;1&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeLineJoin"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="PenLineJoin.Round" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stretch"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="Stretch.Fill" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;False&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;dd:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate&gt;&lt;ControlTemplate&gt;&lt;Rectangle Name="DataShape" Tag="DataShapeTag"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Fill"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBE9" Offset="0" /&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFFA500" Offset="1" /&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stroke"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#FFD69436&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;1&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeLineJoin"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="PenLineJoin.Round" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stretch"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="Stretch.Fill" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;False&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;300&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;200&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Tag"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;DataShape&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle&gt;&lt;/ControlTemplate&gt;&lt;/dd:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate&gt;&lt;/Rectangle&gt; </Content>
```

I tried to obtain this same content value and set it as:

```
myNewItem.Content = (the above shown content)
```

But this is not working for me. What I want to do is, in my code, I set the content manually by using some method, such that the code generates exactly the same shape as I draw in the GUI.

Comment: You're looking for a XamlReader. However it is unclear why you want to do that in the first place. You should really store DATA and not UI. the UI is NOT serializable and you should not attempt to serialize it.

Comment: I just want to generate the same shape as in GUI when I read another xml file. Could you please provide any sample code or a more detailed answer for your point? Thank you.

Comment: `I just want to generate the same shape as in GUI when I read another xml file` - Can you clarify this further? what's in the xml file? are you trying to store the UI in an XML file? if so, that's wrong. You should use proper DataBinding and store DATA in the XML file. Other than that, your requirement is not very clear for me. Can you clarify?

Comment: I store data in the output xml file. There is a 'Content' item tag, which stores the data of the shape in the xml file. I tried to even copy and paste this data content to 'myNewItem.Content', but it is not working. Hope I explained this clearly. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: again, it seems you're trying to serialize the UI. You should really serialize DATA instead. Use DataBinding to bind UI elements' properties to a relevant data model, and then serialize/deserialize the data model. the UI is not serializable.